# Overriding Bootstrap navbar classes - wont work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Alright, so I am having issues overriding some of bootstraps navbar classes. I'm not sure but it works if I use `!important` but I'd rather avoid that at any cost.

So here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
    <li><a>Actions</a></li>
    <li><a>Profile</a></li>
    <li><a>Kingdom</a></li>
    <li><a>Inventory</a></li>
    <li><a>Alliance</a></li>
    <li><a>Mail Box</a></li>
    <li><a href="user/logout">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here are some of the CSS I have tried:

```
.navbar.navbar-nav li a {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

This one doesn't work ^

```
.navbar.navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

Neither does this one ^

```
.navbar-nav li a {
  color: lightgray !important;
}
```

This one is the only one that has worked ^ (I have tried doing it without the `!important` as well.

EDIT: CSS calling

```
  <title># - KoG</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/game/default.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the html embed code for your css files? I assumed you've created a separate `style.css` in which you're placing your custom styles after `bootstrap.css`

Comment: Added to OP for you.

Comment: I just added an id selector to it, and it worked, but I was hoping avoid that.

Comment: Also I would like to add: if i use "nav navbar-nav" in the ul class it works, but "navbar navbar-nav" breaks it, and neither of them work for styling in CSS

Comment: Looks like a matter of **specificity** - you'll need to specify the *right range of selectors to **over-qualify** the intended Bootstrap style rules*. What are the specified Bootstrap selectors for the rule you are trying to overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

This approach is dealing with overwriting specificity issue, as you are overwriting the style provided in `_reboot.scss`(which is part of bootstrap)

[image]

Hence, this is one of solution to achieve, what you are trying  to achieve, your solution must be another way of dealing with this problem.

Example which changes those `li` without `href`

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav a:not([href]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
    <li><a>Actions</a></li>
    <li><a>Profile</a></li>
    <li><a>Kingdom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
    <li><a>Alliance</a></li>
    <li><a>Mail Box</a></li>
    <li><a href="user/logout">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In the below example if you use `.navbar .navbar-nav a`, it will just change those `a` with are having `href`.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav a {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
    <li><a>Actions</a></li>
    <li><a>Profile</a></li>
    <li><a>Kingdom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
    <li><a>Alliance</a></li>
    <li><a>Mail Box</a></li>
    <li><b><a href="user/logout">Logout</a></b></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean? I linked both mine and bootstraps css files. At any rate, I got it to work without whatever it is you are having me try to do.

Comment: @William, so you got it done without `!important` right?

Comment: Yup. I'm not sure what you were trying to get me to do, but I figured it out without doing your suggestion and `!important`